# Adding UITabBarController and have no NavigationController

Tags: xamarin.ios, uitabbarcontroller, appdelegate, navigationcontroller, rootviewcontroller

As I'm new in Xamarin.IOS, I'd like to ask a question. 
I've followed [this example](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/controls/creating_tabbed_applications/) for adding UITabBarController in a Xamarin.IOS project.

When I initialized RootViewController by an instance of TabController, it works fine and I have all tabs. 
BUT my NavigationController set null !  it means that :

1. NavigationItem will disappear
2. navigating between viewControllers are not possible by this code :

   ```
   this.NavigationController.PushViewController(new ProfileViewController(), true);
   ```

because the NavigationController is null ! 
Here is my code in AppDelegate:

```
_tabController = new TabController();
_window.RootViewController = _tabController;
```

and my TabController :

```
public class TabController : UITabBarController
    {

        UIViewController tab1, tab2, tab3, tab4;

        public TabController()
        {
            tab1 = new HomeViewController();
            tab1.TabBarItem.Image = UIImage.FromFile("Icons/Home.png");

            tab2 = new TagCategoryViewController(null, null, 1, null);
            tab2.TabBarItem.Image = UIImage.FromFile("Icons/Tag.png");

            tab3 = new SearchViewController();
            tab3.TabBarItem.Image = UIImage.FromFile("Icons/Search.png");

            tab4 = new ProfileViewController();
            tab4.TabBarItem.Image = UIImage.FromFile("Icons/Home.png");

            var tabs = new UIViewController[] {
                tab1, tab2, tab3,tab4
            };

            ViewControllers = tabs;
        }
    }
```

In additional, I have lots of UIViewControllers and I do all of them programmatically and I dont use StoryBoard !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By wrapping your `TabController` in a `UINavigationController`.

```
_tabController = new TabController();
_window.RootViewController = new UINavigationController(_tabController);
```

This way NavigationController property won't be null and navigation can be done.

Comment: a little question, when I Navigate to a UIViewController which is not in the list of TabController, the tab bar disappear ! Do you know why?

Comment: `UINavigationController` works with Stack navigation. Every `ViewController` that is pushed onto the stack will be shown above the `TabController`. This means that the `TabController` will disappear when pushed to a new `ViewController` and shown when pressing the back button

Comment: So let's imagine, I have ViewController1 with TabController and I want to navigate to ViewController2 (which is not present in TabController) by keeping TabController. How can I do it? 
is it with PushViewController ?

Comment: Instead of updating the question it is better to ask a new question.

Comment: Ok, here is my new question  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47175839/uitabbarcontroller-in-xamarin-ios-without-using-storyboard