# UITabBarController in xamarin.ios without using StoryBoard

Tags: xamarin.ios, appdelegate, navigationcontroller, uitabcontroller

In continue of my question in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47159814/adding-uitabbarcontroller-and-have-no-navigationcontroller/47160970?noredirect=1#comment81299156_47160970), I want to post a complete question which will be a question lots of xamarin.ios developers.

My request is having TabBar in ALL UIViewControllers. So, as I know, there are two ways to realize it.

**First :**

> appDelegate -> set RootViewController : TabController -> UVC1

in this case, I have **NULL** NavigationController and I'll have no navigationItem. and in

> this.NavigationController.PushViewController(new
>   SearchViewController(), true);

It makes error that NavigationController is null.

Here is my code in AppDelegate:

> _tabController = new TabController();
>   _window.RootViewController = _tabController;

and my TabController :

public class TabController : UITabBarController
    {

```
    UIViewController tab1, tab2, tab3, tab4;

    public TabController()
    {
        tab1 = new HomeViewController();
        tab1.TabBarItem.Image = UIImage.FromFile("Icons/Home.png");

        tab2 = new TagCategoryViewController(null, null, 1, null);
        tab2.TabBarItem.Image = UIImage.FromFile("Icons/Tag.png");

        tab3 = new SearchViewController();
        tab3.TabBarItem.Image = UIImage.FromFile("Icons/Search.png");

        tab4 = new ProfileViewController();
        tab4.TabBarItem.Image = UIImage.FromFile("Icons/Home.png");

        var tabs = new UIViewController[] {
            tab1, tab2, tab3,tab4
        };

        ViewControllers = tabs;
    }
}
```

**And the second way :**

> RootViewController -> navigationController -> TabController -> UVC1 ->
>   new UVC2 -> no tab bar !!

Here, everything sounds good, but when I navigate to new UIViewController which is not present in Tabs, the TabBar will diappear !

And the code is :

```
_tabController = new TabController();
var navigationController = new UINavigationController(viewController);
_window.RootViewController = new UINavigationController(_tabController);
```

What can I do ? Any idea?

I don't use StoryBoard !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By wrapping all your `UIViewController` with `UINavigationController` you can enable the behaviour you want, but make sure that you remove `TabBarController` since the `NavigationBar` will overlap the `NavigationBar` from your Views.

```
_window.RootViewController = _tabController;
```

And your views:

```
tab1 = new UINavigationController(new HomeViewController());
tab1.TabBarItem.Image = UIImage.FromFile("Icons/Home.png");
```

Comment: Hey man, thank you so much, you save my life ;) 
Last question, how can I hide tabBar on a uiviewcontroller?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47182764/uitabbarcontroller-in-some-uiviewcontrollers