# XAMARIN.IOS UITabBarController in some UIViewControllers

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios, uinavigationcontroller, tabbar

I have an application (Xamarin.IOS) which start with a UIViewController (Connection view) with no TabBar. But when user Logged, I'd like to add the tabbar that I've created to other views. And vis-versa, when user logged out, I'd like to display the connection view without TabBar.

I know that when I want to display the TabBar, in appDelegate, I have to initialize _window like this :

```
_tabController = new TabController();
_window.RootViewController = _tabController;
_window.MakeKeyAndVisible();
```

and if I want to have a view without TabBar, here is appDelegate:

```
viewController = new ConnectionViewController();
_window.RootViewController = new UINavigationController(viewController);
_window.MakeKeyAndVisible();
```

with this TabController :

```
public class TabController : UITabBarController
    {

        UIViewController tab1, tab2, tab3, tab4;

        public TabController()
        {
            tab1 = new UINavigationController(new ListViewController());
            tab1.Title = Texts.Home;
            tab1.TabBarItem.Image = UIImage.FromFile("Icons/Home@2x.png");

            tab2 = new UINavigationController(new OViewController(1));
            tab2.Title = Texts.Categories;
            tab2.TabBarItem.Image = UIImage.FromFile("Icons/Tag@2x.png");

            tab3 = new UINavigationController(new SearchViewController());
            tab3.Title = Texts.Search;
            tab3.TabBarItem.Image = UIImage.FromFile("Icons/Search@2x.png");

            tab4 = new UINavigationController(new BookmarkViewController(1));
            tab4.Title = Texts.Bookmarks;
            tab4.TabBarItem.Image = UIImage.FromFile("Icons/Favorite@2x.png");


            var tabs = new UIViewController[] {
                tab1, tab2, tab3, tab4
            };

            this.TabBar.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;

            ViewControllers = tabs;
        }
    }
```

But how can I move from a view with TabBar to a view without and vis-versa ?

I don't use StoryBoard and I code on Xamarin.iOS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ## Tab -> No Tab

1. When Push

   ```
   ViewController2 vc2 = new ViewController2();
   vc2.HidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true; //add this line
   this.NavigationController.PushViewController(vc2, true);
   ```
2. When Present

   ```
   this.PresentViewController(new ViewController2(), true, null);
   ```

[image]

> ## No Tab -> Tab

Set Connection Page as RootViewController at first, and then change it when you want to.

Code:

```
public partial class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
{
    UIWindow window;

    public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

        window.RootViewController = new UINavigationController(new ViewController1());
        window.MakeKeyAndVisible();
        return true;
    }

    public void changeRootVC()
    {
        window.RootViewController = new TabController();
    }
}
```

And change it in `Connection Page`

```
if(connected){
     AppDelegate app = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate as AppDelegate;
     app.changeRootVC();
}
```

[image]

Comment: ColeXia, it's perfect for hiding ! It works like a charm ! 
But for the reverse, which means that having a ViewController without TabBar and navigating to another ViewController with TabBar, how can I do? For more detail, the connection VC have no TabBar and in appDelegate, we have a RootViewController with UINavigationController instance and not TabBar, and when the user connect, it will be navigated to a home page which has a TabBar. Do you have any idea on it?

Comment: I think the best way is that  call `_tabController = new TabController();
_window.RootViewController = _tabController;
_window.MakeKeyAndVisible();` from AppDelegate

Comment: but I don't need TabBar in Conncetion page ! In addition, the Connection is not present in my TabBar !