# DecisionNavigationController + TabBarController = 2 navigationsBar

Tags: ios, xamarin, controller, tabbarcontroller

I have a problem with my personal project.
This is my architecture :
[image: Architecture]

Then, my MainViewController can push to TabBarController or another single Controller.
The problem is when I push to the TabBarController, it displays me 2 navigationBar in my 1st controller (from the tabbar)
I can hide the MainController navigation bar to display only the navigation bar from the tabbar but I dont think this is the best practice.

How can I do this ?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is that change the `Window.RootViewController` in `AppDelegate` , so that you don't need to deal with multiple navigation bars.

1. Set `NavigationController` with `MainViewController`  first in `AppDelegate`

   ```
   public partial class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
   {
       UIWindow window;

       public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
       {
           window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

           window.RootViewController = new UINavigationController(new MainViewController());
           window.MakeKeyAndVisible();
           return true;
       }

       public void changeRootVC()
       {
           window.RootViewController = new TabController();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Change `RootViewController` instead of pushing to `TabbarController` in `MainViewController`

   ```
   AppDelegate app = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate as AppDelegate;
   app.changeRootVC();
   ```

Comment: Is it really the good practice to change the rootViewController .. ?

Comment: Yes,it is . refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47182764/xamarin-ios-uitabbarcontroller-in-some-uiviewcontrollers/47195384#47195384 , the window will remove the origin viewcontroller and  show new viewcontroller.

Comment: In general, we will not put tab into navigation , that view hierarchy is too complex and uncontrollable.

Comment: Hi @ColeXia, I just hide my 1st navigation bar if my decision controller push to TabBar. I think the way to have a Decision is good if you have to put some checkpoint in your application